# JQuery SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I've got a submit button inside my modal, and when it's pressed nothing happens! How do I make my form submit when the push my submit button? I don't want to use $('form').submit(); because then php doesn't detect that my button was clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) { 
            //clicking the button shows the modal popup up 
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#AddCareerItem').modal(); 
        });
        $('#btnCancelCareerContent').click(function (e) {
            //close the modal with the cancel button 
            $.modal.close();
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please paste your html and js script, basically what you said could be easily done and maybe the problem is coming from your code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
    //clicking the button shows the modal popup up
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#AddCareerItem').modal();
   });
   $('#btnCancelCareerContent').click(function (e) {
    //close the modal with the cancel button
    $.modal.close();
   });
  });
  </script>

Comment: You may paste your code in the question (edit the question) for better formatting and better for others to read your question :)

Also, can you also paste your html code.

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

From the code you provided, it doesn't appear that you are binding to the submit event. What does the HTML inside #AddCareerItem look like? Are you using an submit input and have a correct form definition?

If you *want* to bind an event, you'll need to use the onShow callback. Something like:

```
$('#AddCareerItem').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
    $("form", dialog.data).submit(function () {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

-Eric

http://www.ericmmartin.com

Answer (score 1):

As jquery UI dialog does, simple-modal takes the buttons out of the < form > element than usually wraps everything in frameworks like ASP.NET and JSF, and prepends them to the < /body > closing tag. So you have to call modal with option persist: true and on clicking the "submit button" close the modal and trigger form submission. You have to close the modal so that the elements return to their normal position in the DOM... :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code I've got. Nothing fancy. The hidden form is inside the form tag and I'm using a submit button.

```
    <form action="somepage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="rw">
            <div class="lb">Title</div>
            <div class="dt"><input type="text" name="txtTitle" value="" /></div>
            <div class="cr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
            <div class="lb">Description</div>
            <div class="dt"><textarea name="txtDescription" ></textarea></div>
            <div class="cr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
            <div class="lb">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dt"><button id="btnAdd" type="button" >Add Career Item</button></div>
            <div class="cr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rw">
            <div class="lb">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dt"><input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" /></div>
            <div class="cr"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="AddCareerItem" style="display:none;">
                <div class="rw">
                    <div class="lb">Type</div>
                    <div class="dt"><select name="drpdwnType" ><option value="1">Duties</option><option value="2">Required</option></select></div>
                    <div class="cr"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rw">
                    <div class="lb">Content</div>
                    <div class="dt">
                        <input name="txtCareerDetailContent" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="cr"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rw">
                    <div class="lb">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="dt"><input type="submit" id="btnAddCareerDetail" name="btnAddCareerDetail" value="Add" /> <input type="button" id="btnCancelCareerContent" value="Cancel" /></div>
                    <div class="cr"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I removed the style tag from my hidden form so I could see it. When I tried to submit it worked fine, but as soon as you click the "Add Career Item", and then try again it won't submit.

Comment: That's strange. It would really help to see the entire thing in action. Do you have a link, or can you put together a sample and email it to me?

Comment: EDIT of the original question would be better to keep stuff together.  If you get answers with upvotes, yours will be pushed down the list.